# How to enable parallel process for OpenCVSharp (OpenMP or CUDA)

Tags: c#, opencv, parallel-processing, openmp

Native OpenCV supports OpenMP to do things parallel.
During compilation if you enable OpenMP, OpenCV uses other processors.
I need to do this thing for OpenCVSharp. I'm using it to capture RTSP stream and I am writing the captured video as a compressed video.

When I look process information It uses single code.
How can I accelerate it ? (Via parallel process or something else.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use the GpuMat in OpenCVSharp.  Here is a documentation link http://shimat.github.io/opencvsharp/html/945fcaac-a182-53a8-c9eb-7b11fb49f6b1.htm.

You can also find some examples on the web as well, although this one is old, but should still point you in the right direction.
http://opencvsharp.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/2.2/OpenCvSharp.Test/Samples/GpuTest.cs